# How can I play only those videos where current time is greater than start time using java script?

Tags: javascript

Unable to retrieve and play the videos

```
<video id="media-video" width="600" height="300" src="http://localhost/CastingGallery/upload/2/php.mp4">        
<source class="" src="http://localhost/CastingGallery/upload/2/marimatrubhasha.mp4" id="videosource" type="video/mp4" startat="00:00:00" endat="00:04:07" name="Gujarati Bhasha" description="This is Gujarati Video">                  
<source class="active" src="http://localhost/CastingGallery/upload/2/php.mp4" id="videosource" type="video/mp4" startat="00:04:07" endat="00:19:06" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">
</video>
```

I want to fetch only those videos where current time is greater than the start time of that video

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mediaPlayer = document.getElementById('media-video');
    var videoSource = mediaPlayer.getElementsByTagName('source');   
    var d=new Date();
    var hh=d.getHours();
    var mm=d.getMinutes();
    var ss=d.getSeconds();
    var currentTime=hh+':'+mm+':'+ss
    console.log('current time is '+currentTime);
    var a=currentTime.split(':');       
    var getStartTime=document.getElementById('videosource').getAttribute('startat');        
    if(currentTime >= getStartTime)
    {   
        var a=currentTime.split(':');
        var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);           
        mediaPlayer.currentTime=seconds;        
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }       
    }); 
   </script>
```

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: unable to get the videos where current time is greater than the start time of that video?

Comment: I have to retrieve the list of videos where current time is greater than the start time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need to iterate through all the `source` elements and compare `startat` attribute.

Also note, you should not have multiple `id` attributes having same `value`

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mediaPlayer = document.getElementById('media-video');
  var videoSource = mediaPlayer.getElementsByTagName('source');
  var d = new Date();
  var hh = d.getHours();
  var mm = d.getMinutes();
  var ss = d.getSeconds();
  var currentTime = hh + ':' + mm + ':' + ss;
  var a = currentTime.split(':');
  var getStartTime = document.getElementById('videosource').getAttribute('startat');


  Array.prototype.forEach.call(videoSource, function(elem) {
    var getStartTime = elem.getAttribute('startat');
    if (currentTime >= getStartTime) {
      alert(elem.getAttribute('name'));
      var a = currentTime.split(':');
      var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
      mediaPlayer.currentTime = seconds;
      mediaPlayer.play();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="media-video" width="600" height="300" src="http://localhost/CastingGallery/upload/2/php.mp4">
  <source class="" src="http://localhost/CastingGallery/upload/2/marimatrubhasha.mp4" id="videosource" type="video/mp4" startat="00:00:00" endat="00:04:07" name="Gujarati Bhasha" description="This is Gujarati Video">
    <source class="active" src="http://localhost/CastingGallery/upload/2/php.mp4" id="videosource" type="video/mp4" startat="00:04:07" endat="00:19:06" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">
</video>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/u8x7xbj4/)

Comment: can I iterate  through all the start time element and compare with the current time. and fetch the video where current time is greater than the start time? please help me.

Comment: thanks for the help but right now retrieve all the video

Comment: What do you mean by __all the start time element__ ?

Comment: var getStartTime = document.getElementById('videosource').getAttribute('startat');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(getStartTime, function(elem) {
      //var getStartTime = elem.getAttribute('startat');
      if (currentTime >= getStartTime) {
        //alert(elem.getAttribute('name'));
        var a = currentTime.split(':');
        var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
        mediaPlayer.currentTime = seconds;
        mediaPlayer.play();
      }
    });

Comment: start time is the startat attribute in source tag of video.

Comment: Use this to select elements by attributes: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/u8x7xbj4/1/

Comment: Thanks Rayon Now I can able to retrieve all the videos where  start time  (startat attribute in source tag) greater than current time . Now I want to play those video when current time and start time of that video is match. Thankyou.

Comment: Got the answer Rayon Dabre. Thanks Bro