# How can I play the video when current time and start time (startat attribute in source tag) is match?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

Here I got the success to retrieve the video where start time (startat attribute in source tag) is greater than the current time. But unable to play the video when time is match

HTML

```
<video id="media-video" width="600" height="300" src="http://localhost/CastingGallery/upload/2/php.mp4">        
<source class="" src="http://localhost/CastingGallery/upload/2/marimatrubhasha.mp4" id="videosource" type="video/mp4" startat="00:00:00" endat="00:04:07" name="Gujarati Bhasha" description="This is Gujarati Video">                  
<source class="active" src="http://localhost/CastingGallery/upload/2/php.mp4" id="videosource" type="video/mp4" startat="00:04:07" endat="00:19:06" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                   
<source class="active" src="http://localhost/CastingGallery/upload/2/php.mp4" id="videosource" type="video/mp4" startat="00:19:06" endat="00:34:05" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                   
<source class="active" src="http://localhost/CastingGallery/upload/2/php.mp4" id="videosource" type="video/mp4" startat="00:34:05" endat="00:49:04" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">           
</video>
```

Java script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mediaPlayer = document.getElementById('media-video');
    var videosource=document.getElementById('source');
    var Startvideo = mediaPlayer.querySelectorAll('source[startat]'); 
    var d=new Date();       
    var hh=d.getHours();        
    var mm=d.getMinutes();      
    var ss=d.getSeconds();
    var timeString = ((hh < 12) ? ":0" : "") + hh;
    timeString  += ((mm < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + mm;
    timeString  += ((ss < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + ss;
    var currentTime=timeString;
    var getStartTime = document.getElementById('videosource').getAttribute('startat');      
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(Startvideo, function(elem) {
    var getStartTime = elem.getAttribute('startat');
    console.log('start time is '+ getStartTime )
    if (getStartTime >= currentTime) {
      var c=elem.getAttribute('src');                   
        mediaPlayer.src=c  
        var currentTimeSecond=currentTime.split(':');
        var getStartTimeSecond=getStartTime.split(':');
        var TimeSecondsCurrent = (+currentTimeSecond[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+currentTimeSecond[1]) * 60 + (+currentTimeSecond[2]);            
        var TimeSecondsGetStart= (+getStartTimeSecond[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+getStartTimeSecond[1]) * 60 + (+getStartTimeSecond[2]);     
      for (var i=TimeSecondsCurrent; i <= TimeSecondsGetStart; i++ ){           
        if(TimeSecondsGetStart == TimeSecondsCurrent){              
            mediaPlayer.play(); 
        }
      }
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Didn't I answer the same question some other day ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509742/how-can-i-play-only-those-videos-where-current-time-is-greater-than-start-time-u/34510123#34510123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var mediaPlayer = document.getElementById('media-video');
var videosource=document.getElementById('source');
var Startvideo = mediaPlayer.querySelectorAll('source[startat]'); 
var d=new Date();       
var hh=d.getHours();        
var mm=d.getMinutes();      
var ss=d.getSeconds();
var timeString = ((hh < 12) ? ":0" : "") + hh;
timeString  += ((mm < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + mm;
timeString  += ((ss < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + ss;
var currentTime=timeString;
var getStartTime = document.getElementById('videosource').getAttribute('startat');      
Array.prototype.forEach.call(Startvideo, function(elem) {
var getStartTime = elem.getAttribute('startat');
console.log('start time is '+ getStartTime )
if (getStartTime >= currentTime) {
  var c=elem.getAttribute('src');
    var currentTimeSecond=currentTime.split(':');
    var getStartTimeSecond=getStartTime.split(':');
    var TimeSecondsCurrent = (+currentTimeSecond[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+currentTimeSecond[1]) * 60 + (+currentTimeSecond[2]);            
    var TimeSecondsGetStart= (+getStartTimeSecond[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+getStartTimeSecond[1]) * 60 + (+getStartTimeSecond[2]);     
    var totalSeconds= TimeSecondsGetStart - TimeSecondsCurrent;
        var totalmiliseconds = totalSeconds * 1000;
        console.log(totalmiliseconds);
        setTimeout(myfunction,totalmiliseconds);
        function myfunction(){          
        var c=elem.getAttribute('src');
        console.log(c);
        mediaPlayer.src=c;                      
        mediaPlayer.play(); 
        }     
}
  });
});
```